# Click the button and save current time and default values in the database (Django)

Tags: python, django, button

When the button "Add" in my browser is clicked, it will automatically save the name (Module 1), current date, and location (Sector 1) to the database.

Here are my codes so far:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Alert(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default='Module 1')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Sector 1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.module
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Alert, Module
from .forms import AlertForm

def home(request):
    context = {
        'modules': Module.objects.all(),
        'alerts': Alert.objects.all(),
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AlertForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Item has been successfully added to the database!'))
            return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', context)

def alert(request, module_id):
    try:
        mdl = Module.objects.get(id=module_id)
    except Module.DoesNotExist:
        mdl = None

    context = {
        'module': mdl,
        'alerts': Alert.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'home/alert.html', context)
```

home.html

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %} 
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
</div>
```

Update:
Here is my code for the urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import AlertListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('alert/<int:module_id>/', views.alert, name='module'),
]
```

Comment: Whats the problem/error ?

Comment: When I click the "Add" button there are no errors, but the alert was not saved in the database.

Comment: Add the `app/urls.py` code.

Comment: Are you using a `ModelForm` in your `forms.py`?

Comment: from django import forms
from .models import Alert

class AlertForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alert
        fields = [
            'module',
            'date',
            'location',
        ]

Comment: Okay, check the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

**Views.py**

> Updated , Tested - works

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AlertForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            abc = form.save(commit=False)
            abc.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Item has been successfully added to the database!'))
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form':form})
```

**html**

```
<form method='post'>{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Add this in your **home.html**

```
{% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is the "as_p" for? I tried your codes above but it is still the same, nothing was saved in the database.

Comment: There is an error on the 'form':'form'
In the line - return render(request, 'home/home.html', 'form':'form')

Comment: Thank you! I can now save alerts to the database. But the message doesn't show and how can I hide the form? I just want to display the Add button.

Comment: For messages i'll update the answer  and for the latter part please ask another question as your initial query has been solved so support this answer by accepting it for other readers with same problem.